How does adding a different solvent affect the position of equilibrium?
Let's say we have an equilibrium in an aqueous solvent, for example:
$$\ce{[Co(H2O)6]^{2+}(aq) + 4Cl^-(aq) \leftrightharpoons [CoCl4]^{2-}(aq) + 6H2O(l)}$$
What happens if I add a miscible solvent such as ethanol? On one hand, I feel like the addition of ethanol will result in a decrease in activity for all species so we shift to the side with the greater stoichiometry (to the right). On the other hand, since the species are dissolved in water, then their effective concentration doesn't change so there is no shift in equilibrium? Are any of these thoughts correct or is there another line of logic that is more accurate?

Consider that saturated solutions of salts in different solvents have the same activity (having the same chemical potential as the solid salt,) Less solubility in less polar solvent means higher activity coefficient.

@Poutnik But wouldn't there still be the same amount of water to keep everything dissolved? I'm A bit confused as to the final conclusion here could you give some clarification

There is not water as solvent any more. There is mixed solvent water  + ethanol. Water would have lower activity and lower abillity to dissolve and to hydrate substances. Another factor is shifting of activity of chloride. Hard to evaluate without data.
